# Finding a row by position

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I am getting an error at position 1996250 in my mysql replication. How can I find out what table/row is at that position?

Comment: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/05/06/debugging-problems-with-row-based-replication/

Comment: Is yours replication statement based or row based?

Comment: How can tell which one it is?

Comment: Thanks Mhasan that link helped.